# Qiskit and IPython conf files do not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, qiskit

I had installed the qiskit-textbook distribution of Qiskit using this command : `pip install git+https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook.git#subdirectory=qiskit-textbook-src`

The tutorial then said to change the contents of the configuration file located at `~/.qiskit/settings.conf` but I can't find the folder at `~/`. I can't find the iPython configuration file either at `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py` for some reason.

How do I fix this?

Comment: you can search filename using the find command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you don't have the `~/.qiskit/settings.conf` you can create that yourself at that location (see this answer [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8702/what-is-the-location-of-the-qiskit-config-file) and the docs [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/configuration.html)).
- If you don't have `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py`, try running `ipython profile create` and see if it then appears.